How do I update my name on a Canadian Aviation Document Booklet?
I am a holder of a Canadian Aviation Document Booklet, however have since legally changed my name and now need to request an ADB with my new name.
The official guidance on updating or renewing only deals with updates to earned licenses and ratings, and the only relevant form is the Application for an Aviation Document Booklet that doesn't have any language relating to applying for an ADB with information that differs from a previously issued one. I can't seem to find any official guidance from Transport Canada at all on what to do in this case.
Do I just submit the application form with the relevant new information (e.g. name, sex) changed? What supporting documentation do I need to provide?

Per an email response to my inquiry from Transport Canada: (strikethrough mine, see below)

Please complete the following form (Flight Crew Licensing Declaration of Name) and submit via email to aviation.ont@tc.gc.ca, along with the required supporting documentation, Apply for a pilot permit or licence (tc.gc.ca).
If you would like your ADB to be re-issued afterward, please include this request in your email as well as the $35 replacement fee receipt.
Payment can be made online here, Online Payment System - Canada.ca (tc.gc.ca).

Edit: After further clarification from Transport Canada the correct way to get an ADB with your new name after submitting the Declaration of Name form is applying for a new ADB following the process on their website.
The required supporting documentation is mentioned on the form itself:

I understand that before further change in my name can be made for licensing purposes, I must submit proof of change of name from the Government of the
Province in which I am residing at this time.

The gender change section of the form simply states "Attach supporting documentation" so it's unclear what's required for that.
Note that aviation.ont@tc.gc.ca is the email for the Ontario Regional Service Centre  - For other regions of Canada the correct contact can be found on this page.
